# deep linking from a app to another

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have two android apps, App1 and App2.

App1 has a MainActivity with a Login button.
App2 has two activities, MainActivity and LoginActivity.
In App1 MainActivity, when the Login button is clicked, it is suppose to link to App2 LoginActivity.

On adb shell, I'm able to launch App2 LoginActivity with the following command:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://login" com.example.android
```

But on App1 MainActivity, when the Login button is clicked, it launched App2 MainActivity instead. What am I missing?

App1 MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Deeplink to authenticator app
                Uri myAction = Uri.parse("example://login");

                PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.android");

                if (intent != null) {
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(myAction);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

App2 AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_label">

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_login">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/login” -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/login" />
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_login">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://login” -->
                <data android:scheme="example"
                    android:host="login" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```